# What particles can be used in the ～よう〇　～まい〇 pattern?

Tags: grammar, particles

In the pattern `～よう　～まい`, I've found from several sources that you can use `が` and `と` (i.e `～ようが　～まいが`), and using one over the other doesn't change the meaning or have a particular nuance. What's confusing me is that I've found [one instance](http://www.renshuu.org/index.php?page=grammar/individual&id=634#mhead751) of this pattern using `か`, and I can't find if there is anything in particular that distinguishes it from the `が / と` version or not, or if it's a typo, or what. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

…ようか…まいか and …ようが…まいが have different meanings.  The fact that they have the same English translation “whether … or not” is a coincidence.

The English expression “whether … or not” has two different usages: (1) as a noun clause, and (2) as an adverbial clause.  For example:

(1) I wonder *whether* I will write to her *or not*.
(2) I will go to New York tomorrow *whether* it rains *or not*.  (= I will go to New York tomorrow *no matter whether* it rains *or not*.)

…ようか…まいか means (1), whereas …ようが…まいが means (2).  Therefore, possible translations of the two sentences above are:

(1) 彼女に手紙を書こうか書くまいか迷う。
(2) 明日、雨が降ろうが降るまいがニューヨークに行く。

(But I think that in (1), …ようか…まいか puts a heavy emphasis on the “whether … or not” part.  A usual way to say (1) without this emphasis is 彼女に手紙を書くかどうか迷う.)