# 「～ようか・～まいか」の後の正確な表現はどれでしょうか？

Tags: grammar, jlpt

新完全マスタN2文法に、この問題があります。

> 「親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか（　　）。」
> a) わからない　b) 3日も考えている　c) 関係ない

どうして (b) が正解ですか、また (a), (c) はどこが間違いですか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「～おうか～まいか」is used when describing a situation where you are weighing two opposing options (an action and an inaction, to be precise), and it is followed by a verb phrase that denotes or implies serious consideration or deliberation.

c) 関係ない ('is irrelevant') is an obviously wrong choice, since, for one thing, its meaning does not involve any kind or amount of thinking.

The ill-suitedness of a) わからない ('not know') is much subtler, but I believe  it's due to the fact that the state of not knowing/わからない does not necessarily imply that you have put some serious thought into a matter at hand; you can not know whether you should tell the truth or not tell the truth as well without debating the question as after debating it.

Although a) わからない might not be outright ungrammatical here (the resulting sentence would be perfectly comprehensible to me), it has a risk of failing to meet (what I take to be) the requirement that 「～おうか～まいか」 must be used with a verb phrase that at least implies some deliberation.

Therefore, b) 3日も考えている, which clearly pass that test, is the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

## 日本語

(a), (b), (c) の中で文法的に正しいのは (b) だけです。なぜかと言うと、

> 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか3日も考えている。
>   = 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**と**3日も考えている。

なのですが、

> × 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**と**わからない。
>   × 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**と**関係ない。

とは言えないからです（「～と関係ない」という表現はありますが、引用の「と」ではなく並列の「と」です）。

言い換えれば、「～ようか～まいか」は単に述語の内容を説明する**同格の副詞節**としてのみ機能し、主語や目的語などとして述語の項を補ってはくれません。もし以下のように助詞を付け加えて**名詞節**に変換すれば、(a) (c)も文法的に正しくなります。

> a′) ○ 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**が**わからない。
>   c′) ○ 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**に（は）**​関係ない。

この挙動は普通の「～か～か」節と比べても特異です。「～か～か」の構文自体は（英語の whether のように）名詞節として使えるからです。

> 親に本当のことを言ったか言っていないかわからない。
>   = 親に本当のことを言ったか言っていないか**が**わからない。
>
> 親に本当のことを言ったか言っていないか確かめる。
>   = 親に本当のことを言ったか言っていないか**を**確かめる。

## English

Among (a), (b), and (c), only (b) is the grammatical one. The reason is,

> 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか3日も考えている。
>   = 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**と**3日も考えている。

while you can't say

> × 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**と**わからない。
>   × 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**と**関係ない。

(The collocation ～と関係ない does exist, but this one is a different と that means "with/and".)

In other words, ～ようか～まいか only functions as **adverbial clause of apposition** that qualifies the predicate to depict what it is like, not as a verb's argument such as *subject* or *object*. In order to make (a) and (c) grammatical, you could put additional particles to make them into **noun clauses**.

> a′) ○ 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**が**わからない。
>   c′) ○ 親に本当のことを言おうか言うまいか**に（は）**​関係ない。

This behavior is, however, quite peculiar among similar ～か～か constructions, because ordinarily they just work as noun clauses by themselves (alike to English *whether*).

> 親に本当のことを言ったか言っていないかわからない。
>   = 親に本当のことを言ったか言っていないか**が**わからない。
>
> 親に本当のことを言ったか言っていないか確かめる。
>   = 親に本当のことを言ったか言っていないか**を**確かめる。

Answer (score 1):

～ようか～まいか is almost always followed by verbs like 悩む, 迷う, 考える or 思い巡らす. Even if you omit such verbs, ～ようか～まいか on its own expresses one's consideration, hesitation, etc. It's probably best to memorize this construction with these verbs. See: [Learn JLPT N1 Grammar: （よ）うか～まいか (you ka~mai ka)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%EF%BC%88%E3%82%88%EF%BC%89%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B-you-kamai-ka/)

To use わからない, you have to say either 言うべきか言わないべきかわからない or 言うべきか言わざるべきかわからない. The latter is more literary.

To use 関係ない, you have to say either 言おう**が**言うまい**が**関係ない or 言おう**と**言うまい**と**関係ない. This ～ようが～まいが or ～ようと～まいと is "(*regardless of*) whether A or B" or "be it A or B" rather than simple "whether A or B" as a noun clause. For similar examples, see: [Learn JLPT N1 Grammar: （よ）うが～まいが (you ga~mai ga)](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%EF%BC%88%E3%82%88%EF%BC%89%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%8C-you-gamai-ga/)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5749/7944

Answer (score 0):

「～おうか～まいか」とは、なにするかまだ迷っている文法です。

質問の例題を訳せば、「I'm uncertain about saying the truth to my parents. I'm been thinking it over for 3 days.」となります。

上の説明は、TRY!N2というN2向けの教科書から出ました。